# in vue.js how do I serve components that require js libraries?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

So I'm new to the Vue CLI and one of the features that I would like to use is

```
vue serve <component name>
```

The problem I am immediately running into is there are some js libraries like moment that I am using in those components, so do I need to add an import statement in my component just for local testing?  Is there anyway to set this globally and if so can I access it when i try to serve an individual component?

Answer (score 1):

Once you run `npm i -s moment`, you can either import moment in your `main.js` Vue entry point, like this:

```
import moment from 'moment';

Vue.use(moment);
```

Or, you can use it locally in your component script, with just a local import within the `<script></script>` tag.

```
import moment from 'moment';
```

My preference is the former, since it allows me to reduce duplication if I need it in multiple files. Either way, to access in a function, once it is imported in one of those two ways, you can use it in component methods and lifecycle hooks.

Answer (score 0):

Import your plugins in your main.js and then use like so;

```
import Vue from "vue"; 
//this is called only once before you start importing other packages

import YourPlugin from "yourplugin"; 
Vue.use(YourPlugin)
```